# jquery offset() and position()

Tags: jquery, position, parent, offset

I need to get position of element relative to its parent. `position()` is suppose to do that but it looks like it doesn't.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <style>

  body{padding: 0px; margin: 0px;}
  div { margin-left: 200px; padding: 30px; border: 1px solid red;}
  p { margin: 0px; padding: 0px; border: 1px solid black }
  </style>
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.5.js"></script>

    <script>
        $(document).ready(function() {

            var p = $("p.paragraf");
            var position = p.offset();
            $("p.zadnji").text( "left: " + position.left + ", top: " + position.top );

        });
    </script>  

</head>
<body>

<div class="container">
  <p class="paragraf">Hello</p>
</div>
<p class="zadnji"></p>

</body>
</html>
```

Result:

> left: 231, top: 31

If `p.paragraf` is inside `#container` then `#container` should be parent to `p.paragraf`. If padding of `#container` is set to 30px, shouldn't both left and top position of  `p.paragraf` be 30px?

I tried `offset()` but it gives the same result as `position()`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Aloha,

Add position: relative; to your container style

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/FpK7V/) example

Comment: yep, I missed to add "relative"